# Добавление изображения номенклатуры по ссылке 1С

Tags: 1с

Помогите, пожалуйста, 2 дня уже сижу пытаюсь сделать. Задача такая: есть ссылка на изображение, например https://static.techspot.com/images/products/2018/loudspeakers/org/2019-02-13-product-9.jpg
Необходимо задать это изображение номенклатуре через ВременноеХранилище. Что только не пытался делать.
Последнее что есть:

```
АдресИзображения = СтруктураЭлемента.Изображение;
            
        hh = Новый HTTPЗапрос(АдресИзображения);
        дд = hh.ПолучитьТелоКакДвоичныеДанные();
        АдресВременногоХранилища = ПоместитьВоВременноеХранилище(дд);
        ФайлКартинки = Новый Файл (АдресВременногоХранилища);
        
        ПараметрыФайла = Новый Структура("Автор,ВладелецФайлов,ИмяБезРасширения,РасширениеБезТочки,ВремяИзмененияУниверсальное");
        ПараметрыФайла.Автор = Пользователи.АвторизованныйПользователь();
        ПараметрыФайла.ВладелецФайлов = Элемент.Ссылка;
        ПараметрыФайла.ИмяБезРасширения = ФайлКартинки.ИмяБезРасширения ;
        ПараметрыФайла.РасширениеБезТочки = СтрЗаменить (ФайлКартинки.Расширение, ".", "");
        ПараметрыФайла.ВремяИзмененияУниверсальное = ТекущаяДата();
        
        
                
        Попытка
            СсылкаНаКартинку = РаботаСФайлами.ДобавитьФайл(ПараметрыФайла,АдресВременногоХранилища); 
        Исключение
            Сообщить ("Ошибка добавления файла: " + ОписаниеОшибки());
        КонецПопытки;
        
        Попытка 
            Элемент.ФайлКартинки = СсылкаНаКартинку;
            Элемент.Записать();
        Исключение
            Сообщить ("Картинка не добавлена: " + ОписаниеОшибки());
        КонецПопытки;
```

Не работает, выдает "Ошибка добавления файла: {ОбщийМодуль.РаботаСФайлами.Модуль(541)}: Значение не является значением объектного типа (Размер)"

Answer (score 1):

Допустим, на управляемой форме задан реквизит ФайлКартинки с типом Строка, вынесен на форму как ПолеКартинки. Так же созданы две команды.
Как то так:

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура Команда1(Команда)
// чтение локального файла
    Д = Новый ДвоичныеДанные("C:\Temp\2019-02-13-product-9.jpg");
    ФайлКартинки = ПоместитьВоВременноеХранилище(Д);
        
КонецПроцедуры

&НаКлиенте
Процедура Команда2(Команда)
// чтение из интеренета
    Соединение = Новый HTTPСоединение("static.techspot.com", 443,,,,, Новый ЗащищенноеСоединениеOpenSSL());
    hh = Новый HTTPЗапрос("images/products/2018/loudspeakers/org/2019-02-13-product-9.jpg");
    Ответ = Соединение.Получить(hh);
    дд = Ответ.ПолучитьТелоКакДвоичныеДанные();
    ФайлКартинки = ПоместитьВоВременноеХранилище(дд);
    
КонецПроцедуры
```

Comment: Спасибо, но проблема в том, что ссылки на картинки имеют разных хостов. То есть там может быть та ссылка, которую я указал, а может быть ссылка  на совершенно другой сайт. Например, https://superphotos.com/images/products/2018/loudspeakers/org/2019-02-13-product-9.jpg

Comment: Тогда парсите ссылку. Простой вариант:
<br/>
Линк = "https://static.techspot.com/images/products/2018/loudspeakers/org/2019-02-13-product-9.jpg";  
Части = СтрРазделить(Линк, "/", Ложь);  
АдресХоста = Части[1];  
ПутьКартинка = СтрЗаменить(Линк, Части[0] + "//" + Части[1] + "/", "");